# No more than two pages on the Stack Exchange homepage

Tags: support, stack-exchange

On the Stack Exchange home page, https://stackexchange.com/, one can see that one cannot go to page 3, assuming 50 rows are shown in a single page.

Is this function deliberate or a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the Stack Exchange home page only shows the [*hot network questions* list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/what-are-the-criteria-for-questions-to-be-selected-for-hot-network-questions), and there are never more than 100 of those.

That's not a bug, that's deliberate. This is the list from which [30 random posts are picked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222991/ease-up-on-the-hot-network-question-randomness/222993#222993) to show in the sidebar of almost every page of every site in the network.

So yes, when you set the *per page* size to 50, there will only be 2 pages. At 30, you'll see 4 pages, and at 15, there will be 7 pages, and both of those have only 10 items on the last page.